# Scala Regex capture separate groups

Tags: regex, scala, regex-group

I need to capture 3 groups separately.
For ex:

s3://some/path/TIMESTAMP/part-1234.parquet

|----- g1 ---------|------ g2 ------|--------- g3 ---------|

where g3 is the file name, g2 is the TIMESTAMP and g1 is anything that precedes the timestamp

I've come up with capturing 2 groups using scala:

```
val pattern = "(.*?)(part.*.parquet)$".r
val pattern(fileBasePath, filename) = row.file_path
```

what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
val pattern(fileBasePath, timestamp, filename) = row.file_path
```

What would the pattern look like for the above?

Comment: yep, that would work. please post it as an answer , I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```scala
val pattern = """^(.*?)/([^/]+)/(part.*\.parquet)$""".r
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JIRCul/1).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/]+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(part.*\.parquet)` - Group 3: `part`, any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible and then a `.parquet` substring
- `$` - end of string.